# How to set the JDK compile and target class version in maven pom file?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I have seen similar questions asked, but their answers are not suitable for my question.

I have JDK 11 installed on my system(JAVA_HOME etc.) and configured in the Eclipse Java compiler option as well.

Now in my pom file, I am setting like...

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.12.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>11</source>
                <target>11</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
     </plugins>
   </build>
```

Some other examples mention like..
[image: Setting JDK source, target]

Are these two things going to achieve the same thing ? If so, which one is a better method ?

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html

Comment: The configuration part `source`/`target` is exactly the same as using the properties `<maven.compiler.source>` / `<maven.compiler.target>` (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#source) check the entry `User Property` which contains exactly that reference... From JDK9+ on I strongly recommend to use `<maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>`(https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#release)  instead

Comment: I recommend to use the property setup because those properties are also picked up by other plugins (for example maven-javadoc-plugin etc.) so that makes the setup easier...

Comment: Thanks for your response. I found the answer, I was looking for.
Using maven-compiler-plugin or maven.compiler.source/maven.compiler.target properties are equivalent.

Comment: But I strongly recommend to use `<maven.compiler.release>..</maven.compiler.release>` instead... (for JDK9+)...